# Python - with statement with optional object

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, with-statement

I have a script that processes some data and if a database/file is present, writes some data into it. I specify the database or file as `configargparse`(`argparse`) argument. I need to clean (close file, db) in some organized way in case exceptions occur.

Here is my init:

```
import sqlite3
import confargparse
import sys
parser.ArgParser(...) 
parser.add('--database', dest='database',
    help='path to database with grabbers', metavar='FILE',
    type=lambda x: arghelper.is_valid_file(parser, x))
parser.add('-f', '--file', type=configargparse.FileType(mode='r'))
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I did it using `if` and `try`:

```
if args.database:
    conn = sqlite3.connect(args.database)
    c = conn.cursor()
# same init for file

try:
    while True: # do something, it might be moved to some main() function
        result = foo()
        if args.database:
            c.execute('Write to database {}'.format(result))
        # same
            # for file        
finally:
    if args.database:
        conn.close() 
    # same
        # for file
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'keyboard interrupt'
```

Can it be done with the `with` statement?  Something like (here comes `()?():()` from C):

```
with ((args.database)?
      (conn = sqlite3.connect(args.database)):
      (None)) as db, same for file:
```

and then refer to the db inside the `with` clause and check if they exist?

Comment: Could you just let file default to `os.devnull` and db default to `:memory:`?

Comment: I should close file and db on the (unexpected) end. can I run `.close()' in such cases?

Comment: If you use the file path [`/dev/null/'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device), you can open, write to and close it as you would any other file. For the database, sqlite lets you create an ['in-memory'](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) database that is lost when the execution ends. There may be memory issues if you have a lot of data; I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question first. It can be done, using `contextlib`. But I'm not sure how much you would gain from this.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def uncertain_conn(args):
    yield sqlite3.connect(args.database) if args.database else None

# Then you use it like this
with uncertain_conn(args) as conn:
    # conn will be the value yielded by uncertain_conn(args)
    if conn is not None:
        try:
            # ...
```

But as I said, while turning a generator function into a context manager is cool and personally I really like the `contextmanager` decorator, and it does give you the functionality you say you want, I don't know if it really helps you that much here. If I were you I'd probably just be happy with `if`:

```
if args.database:
    conn = sqlite3.connect(args.database)
    try:
       # ...
```

There *are* a couple of things you can simplify with `with`, though. Check out `closing`, also from `contextlib` (really simple, I'll just quote the documentation):

> **`contextlib.closing(thing)`**
>
> Return a context manager that closes thing
>   upon completion of the block. This is basically equivalent to:
>
> ```
> from contextlib import contextmanager
>
> @contextmanager def closing(thing):
>     try:
>         yield thing
>     finally:
>         thing.close()
> ```

So the above code can become:

```
if args.database:
    conn = sqlite3.connect(args.database)
    with closing(conn):
        # do something; conn.close() will be called no matter what
```

But this won't print a nice message for `KeyboardInterrupt`. If you really need that, then I guess you still to have to write out the `try-except-finally` yourself. Doing anything more fanciful is probably not worth it. (And note that `except` must precede `finally`, otherwise you get a syntax error.)

And you can even do this with `suppress` (but requires a bit of caution; see below)

```
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(TypeError):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(args.database or None)
    with closing(conn):
        # do business
```

`with suppress(error): do_thing` is equivalent to

```
try:
    do_thing
except error:
    pass
```

So if `args.database` evaluates to `False`, the second line is effectively `connect(None)`, which raises a `TypeError`, which will be caught by the context manager and the code below will be skipped. But the risk is that it will suppress all `TypeError`s in its scope, and you may not want that.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own context manager in such cases.  Create one which handles both connections.  A context manager is a class which has methods `__enter__()` and `__exit__()`.  One is called before entering the `with` clause, one is called when it is left (how ever).

Here's an example for how to do this in your case:

```
def f(cond1, cond2):

  class MultiConnectionContextManager(object):
    def __init__(self, cond1, cond2):
      self.cond1 = cond1
      self.cond2 = cond2
    def __enter__(self):
      print "entering ..."
      if self.cond1:
        # self.connection1 = open(...)
        print "opening connection1"
      if self.cond2:
        # self.connection1 = open(...)
        print "opening connection2"
      return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
      print "exiting ..."
      if self.cond1:
        # self.connection1.close()
        print "closing connection1"
      if self.cond2:
        # self.connection2.close()
        print "closing connection2"

  with MultiConnectionContextManager(cond1, cond2) as handle:
    if cond1:
      # handle.connection1.read()
      print "using handle.connection1"
    if cond2:
      # handle.connection2.read()
      print "using handle.connection2"

for cond1 in (False, True):
  for cond2 in (False, True):
    print "=====", cond1, cond2
    f(cond1, cond2)
```

You can call this directly to see the outcome.  Replace the `print`s with your real statements for opening, using, and closing the connections.